# WPF DataGrid ItemsSource Binding Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Here is my problem.  I have a WPF datagrid and I am binding the .ItemsSource to a linq query IEnumerable result.  This works great.  When I run the program the data is loaded correctly in the datagrid.  My problem is too much data is displayed.  (IE users don't need to see ID fields, etc).  What I am attempting to do is after I bind to the .ItemsSource, I want to hide a few columns.  I have found the .Visibility and attempting to set it, but the **columns object is empty.**  After the binding I have tried the following methods: .Items.Refresh() and .UpdateLayout().

My question is what method do I need to call to refresh the columns after I set the .ItemsSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not explicitly setup your DataGrid? http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html -- This will help you be able to setup your DataGrid manually instead of having it use AutoGenerated columns.

Comment: I can if it have too, but I would rather not explicitly define the columns.  To me, it seems that there has to be something to make the columns object populate after setting the itemssource.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution could be changing your linq query.  Simply select the columns you wish to display, like so:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = myquery.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Age = x.Age });
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that initially, but if it need the ID, I have to do a lookup against name...  Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the .Visibility of DataGrid column, do it after loading of data in the DataGrid. DataGrid is not getting loaded just after the binding of ItemSource; that's why you are getting empty column objects.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That is essential what I was attempting to do. I wanted a manual way force the loading after the binding of the ItemSource so that I could call the visibility property of the column directly afterwards.  But I couldn't find a way.